# memory segmentation in 8086 !! . About the not so popular memory segments in 8086 and christsake this title thingy is really hard

Tags: intel, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I know that  the 1mb memory of 8086 is split  into 16 logical sections but i only know about 4 such locations ,would anyone tell about the rest ?

Comment: Any of the segment registers (CS, DS, ES, SS) can point at the entire memory space in 16 byte increments - the effective address is always calculated as `segment register * 16 + offset register`. So I have no idea what you mean by "i only know about 4 such locations"?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [that](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29)? It would be easier for us, if you tell us your four known locations.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the 1mb memory of 8086 is split into 16 logical sections

I understand what you're saying but I'm afraid it's worse than that!
The 1MB memory has actually 65536 logical sections each overlapping the next by 65520 bytes. *Your* 16 logical sections are just special cases that happen to start at linear addresses divisable by 65536.

> but i only know about 4 such locations

It's not clear what you mean by this but I think that you are referring to the segment registers CS, DS, ES, and SS. These are not *locations* as such but rather they each provide a pointer to any one of the forementioned sections. A linear address gets calculated by multiplying the appropiate segment register by 16 and then adding in the offset address. The result of this calculation is then truncated to have 20 bits only.

> ,would anyone tell about the rest ?

Simple enough. There's nothing else.